# Export to Excel a div content separate rows and cells using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to export div data which using Jquery. But value is coming same cell

Here the Example image:

[image]

I need below Example image:

[image]

Something missed my code please help me.

JS:

```
var csvContent= "First Name, Middle Name, Last Name"; // Headers for CSV file


var dataElements = document.getElementsByClassName("sample");
for (var i = 0; i < dataElements.length; i++) {     // we iterate through all data entries
// If your ids per entry (one person) are fix (which is a bad idea)
var entryLineCsv = document.getElementById("kaf70").innerHTML + "," 
                 + document.getElementById("kaf71").innerHTML + ","
                 +document.getElementById("kaf72").innerHTML + ",";  // here we got on csv line
 createCsvFile(entryLineCsv);
 }

 function createCsvFile(addEntryLineIoCsv) {


  let file = new Blob([csvContent = csvContent + addEntryLineIoCsv], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });

    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

   let a = $("<a />", {

        href: url,

        download: "filename.xls"

    }).appendTo("body").get(0).click();


 }
```

HTML:

```
div class="losSection" id="secReviewerDemographics"><div class="losSectionHeader"><div class="losSectionSel losSectionTitle misign" data-originaltitle="Demographics">Demographics</div></div><div id="cpC_kf_secview_50" class="losSectionView"><div>




   <div id="ExportDetails" class="sample">

      <div class="tabularView">

         <input type="hidden" name="kaf_78" id="kaf_78" aria-label="kaf_78" value="01" class="._shCE"> 

         <div id="cpC_ctl73" class="tabularTbl flex-row start-xs">

           <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">

                  <div style="">

                     <label for="kaf_70" id="klb_70" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">First Name

                     </label>

                  </div>

               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">

                  <div class="labelValueField">

                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_70" id="kaf_70">

                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_70" id="kaf70" aria-label="Applicant First Name">NAMA</span>

                     </span>

                  </div>

               </div>

            </div>

            <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">

                  <div style="">

                     <label for="kaf_71" id="klb_71" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">Middle Name</label>

                  </div>

               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">

                  <div class="labelValueField">

                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_71" id="kaf_71">

                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_71" id="kaf71" aria-label="Applicant Middle Name">VEENESH</span>

                     </span>

                  </div>

               </div>

            </div>

            <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">

                  <div style="">

                     <label for="kaf_72" id="klb_72" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">Last Name

                     </label>

                  </div>

               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">

                  <div class="labelValueField">

                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_72" id="kaf_72">

                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_72" id="kaf72" aria-label="Applicant Last Name">KUMAR</span>

                     </span>

                  </div>

               </div>

            </div>



         </div>

         </div>

   </div>




                </div></div>

    <button id="ExportToExcel" onclick="exportF(this)">Export To Excel</button>
```

DEMO Code: [**DEMO LiNK**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/Lv7ch8zj/3/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Export to Excel a div content using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797469/how-to-export-to-excel-a-div-content-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is the syntax you're using to create the Blob is invalid. You're using an expression yet you need to actually provide the data. Secondly you're attempting to create an XLS file in plain text, which is not how that file format works.

The simplest way to achieve this is to create a CSV file, which is formatted in the manner you create the strings, you simply need to separate each line of the CSV with a line break.

Finally, as you're using jQuery, the syntax to retrieve the data can be simplified by using nested `map()` calls to create an array for each line of the output. Try this:

```js
let csv = $('.sample').map((i, sample) => {
  return $(sample).find('span > .labelValue').map((_, field) => field.innerText).get().join(',');
}).get();
csv.unshift('First Name,Middle Name,Last Name'); // add headers
createCsvFile(csv);

function createCsvFile(csvArray) {
  let file = new Blob([csvArray.join('\r\n')], { type: "application/csv" });
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  let a = $("<a />", {
    href: url,
    download: "filename.csv"
  }).appendTo("body").get(0).click();
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5ft27gu0/5/)

Note that I added multiple lines to the jsFiddle example so you can see how extensible it is.

Comment: One More Doubt <div class="losSectionSel losSectionTitle misign" data-originaltitle="Demographics">Demographics</div>   Demographics is a section Name i want this name is excel sheet Name please help me.Replace filename to Demographics